# getting rank of a row in a rowset

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following rows :

```
id        name        score

1         Bill        0
2         Kim         8
3         Michael     30
4         Doug        22
5         Mellisa     1
```

When I do `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY score DESC`, I get

```
id        name        score

4         Doug        22
3         Michael     30
2         Kim         8
5         Mellisa     1
1         Bill        0
```

Now I want  to get only one row, so I'll add a where clause, but problem is the ranking.

I'm producing *pseudo ranks* in my php code, i.e. the first row in the rowset is assigned rank 1, second is assigned rank 2 and so on...

So when I do `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 5`, apparently all the rank information is lost. How to get over this problem? Is there any way I could get the position of the row in rowset before adding the where clause?

Answer (score 4):

Wrap the query in a subquery so that the rank will be preserved. Here's an example,

```
-- the example produces rank based on highest score.
SELECT  *
FROM
        (
            SELECT  @rank := ifnull(@rank, 0) + 1 Rank,
                    Id, name, Score
            FROM    tableName a
            ORDER   BY Score DESC
        ) x
WHERE   ID = 5
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7dc7b/3)

Comment: i prefer `@rank = ifnull(@rank, 0) + 1` and no cryptic select in the from clause, but +1. See http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7dc7b/3

Comment: @Bohemian let me try that. anyway the OP has implemented his own way of sorting `:)`

Comment: I left your at-best-questionable formatting out of respect, but I couldn't resist cleaning up the UDV initialization kung fu

Comment: you are mixing old and new syntax, replace the `comma` with `CROSS JOIN`, here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1ce13/4

Comment: @JW웃 nope, it definitely breaks when using joins. The fiddle you provided shows that Mellisa had rank 5 whereas on removing the join clause I get rank 4 which is correct. have a look at this : sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1ce13/7

Comment: @JW웃 what if my scores are dependent on an external table? http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69d7e/7

Comment: @Bohemian: Judging by the SQL Fiddle demo, the query you've edited in seems to be returning different results from JW's original suggestion. (Those results appear to be incorrect too.)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, name, score, FIND_IN_SET( score, (
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( score
ORDER BY score DESC ) 
FROM ScoreDetail)
) AS rank
FROM ScoreDetail
Where id=5
```

This will solve your problem....